# Why subprocess.Popen.communicate() does not return the output?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have a function for checking network devices by ip for liveness ?

```
from subprocess import run, Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL
import time

def ping():
    result = Popen(['ping', '192.168.0.1'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, 
                     shell=True, text=True)
    out, err = result.communicate()
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Output: ', out)
```

and called the function

```
ping()
```

But nothing is returned as param **out**.
Please help me with this issue! Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: On Linux ping doesn't stop by itself unless you give it a `-c` option to specify the number of messages to send. Try `['ping', '-c', '5', '192.168.0.1']`

Comment: Yes, I am in windows.

Comment: Try removing `shell=True`

Comment: Abdul Niyas , thanks a lot, it just working. Can you explain your solution somehow, please !

Comment: Read the documentation.  It explains quite clearly what shell=True does.

Comment: You should check `result.returncode`. Its program specific, but usually anything other than 0 is an error. You could also print `err` to see what the error message is.